# Calculate Sum Then Percentage of Sum by Row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a database that looks like this:

```
STAFF  Position_Group FTE
BOB     APP           1.0
Mike    APP           0.5
Ken     APP           0.8
Liz     APP           0.7
Sally   APP           0.6
```

total = 3.6

I want to total the FTE column and then divide each Staff member by the total resulting in a new data table that looks like this:

```
STAFF  Position_Group  FTE  %_Total_FTE
BOB     APP            1.0  .27
Mike    APP            0.5  .14
Ken     APP            0.8  .22
Liz     APP            0.7  .19
Sally   APP            0.6  .16
```

I know how to total FTE column by doing this, but I'm not sure how to apply it to calculate the % column.

```
Master_PG_ROC_CFTE = Master_PG_ROC_v1.groupby(['Position_Group']).agg({'FTE': ['sum']})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby().transform()` to propagate the sum across the rows:

```
df['%Total_FTE'] = df['FTE'] / df.groupby('Position_Group')['FTE'].transform('sum')
```

Output:

```
   STAFF Position_Group  FTE  %Total_FTE
0    BOB            APP  1.0    0.277778
1   Mike            APP  0.5    0.138889
2    Ken            APP  0.8    0.222222
3    Liz            APP  0.7    0.194444
4  Sally            APP  0.6    0.166667
```

Answer (score 1):

Fix your code

```
Master_PG_ROC_CFTE = Master_PG_ROC_v1.groupby(['Position_Group'])['FTE'].sum()

Master_PG_ROC_v1['%Total_FTE'] = Master_PG_ROC_v1['FTE'] / Master_PG_ROC_CFTE.reindex(Master_PG_ROC_v1['Position_Group']).values
```